# Is there any way to backup ACLs and all advance attributes(encrypted or compressed) using python?

Tags: windows, file, python-3.x, directory, backup

Like backupread() and backupwrite() api in windows which backs up file with all permissions and security information.Is there any module in python which does this or is it possible using python?